# Add rows of from other Excel files

Tags: vba, excel

I have 10 Excel files that each of them has 5 sheets. I want to have a `One.xls` file with 5 sheets contains all rows of that 10 excel files.

I found some softwares but none of them is free. I want to write it with Macro. how could I do it.

Comment: By recording a macro and then amending it to suit your needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best place to start is excelforum.com for specific answers but in short you need to lay it out into the following processes;
1) define the variable names for your one.xlsx workbook and sheet names so you can switch back
2) define the workbooks and associated file paths that you want to open
3) Open workbook 1
4) select the data
5) copy and paste into the master workbook
6) close workbook 1
7) repeat steps 3 - 6 for the other workbooks

that'll bring it into one consolidated list.  Things to consider are whether you want to wipe what's in the spreadsheet already or add to the bottom so you may need a few error traps or cleansing tools to begin with.